# Kivy Unable to Update the action button Icon

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm building a Kivy interface with raspberry pi module. Unfortunately I'm unable to change the icon when Ethernet disconnected on Action bar.I already assign a Icon when Ethernet cable connected but when disconnected it doesn't update the icon in  my Asset folder.Basically app works when i use over and over use the same Icon on Kivy file.(EE1.png and mm.png).

```html
class Menu(BoxLayout):
    manager = ObjectProperty(None)
    

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Menu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self._key_handler)
        logger.setErrorIcon = self.setErrorIcon
        #btn1 = ActionButton(text='',icon='./assest/usb.jpg')

    def _key_handler(self, instance, key, *args):
        if key is 27:
            self.set_previous_screen()
            return True

            
    def is_connected(self, *args):
        
        motorBtn = StringProperty()
        index = NumericProperty(-1)
        
        try
            socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
            self.ids.EthBtn.icon = './Asset/EE1.png'
            logger.debug("connected")
           
        except OSError:
            
            self.ids.EthBtn.icon = './Asset/EE.png'<<<<This Icon doesnt shows
     logger.error("E81:not connected")
```

```html
ActionBar:
        
        size_hint_y: 0.15
        background_image: ''
        background_color: 0.349, 0.584, 0.917, 1
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                id: actprev
                title: "[b]RheoSB[/b]"
                markup: True
                ##color: 0.105, 0.109, 0.113,1
                font_size: 100
                #app_icon: './assest/v3.jpg'
                app_icon: './Asset/VL2.png'
                with_previous: False
                ##on_release: root.set_previous_screen()
                #on_press: root.manager.current= 'home'
                on_press: root.set_previous_screen()
                on_press: root.btn_SwipeSound()

             
            ActionButton:
                id:errorBtn
                text:''
                icon: ''
                on_press:root.error_logPopup()
               
            ActionButton:
                id:EthBtn
                important: True
                text:''
                icon: './Asset/EE1.png'<<<<<

            ActionButton:
                id:motorBtn
                text:''
                icon: './Asset/mm.png'
```

But When I Change the

```
except OSError:

            self.ids.EthBtn.icon = './Asset/EE.png'
```

to

```
`except OSError:

         self.ids.EthBtn.icon = './Asset/mm.png'`
```

it shows the mm.png icon.

**EDIT**
instead of

```
class MenuApp(App):
index = NumericProperty(-1)

def build(self):
    my_callback = Menu()
    Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback.is_connected, 0.5)
    return my_callback    # Menu()
```

I used `*BackgroundScheduler()*`  to callback  `*is_connected()*` method this cause me the issue. Could you explain me why this happens please!!

```
class MenuApp(FlatApp):


def build(self):
    my_callback=Menu()
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(my_callback.is_connected, 'interval', seconds=1)
    #scheduler.add_job(ip_call.update_ip, 'interval', seconds=1)
    scheduler.start()
    return my_callback
```

**EDIT EDIT**
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#basic-concepts
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/background.html#apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler

in the code `from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler`  i just import the library and start to use it tbh. Never thought about to use the kivy clock schedule before..

Comment: In one place you reference `EE.png` and in another you reference `EE1.png`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Kevin: Your code runs fine i.e. when Internet is disconnected, it displayed a different icon. Does `EE.png` exist in folder, `.Asset`?

Comment: Hi @ikolim yes EE.png is in my ./Asset folder.All three icons(EE1.png/mm.png/EEpng) in the ./Asset folder.When I change the disconnected Icon to mm.png.App works.But I want to  display a different icon.

Comment: @Kevin: Could please share all three icons so that we can test it. Thank you.

Comment: @ikolim please refer the Edit section on question.

Comment: @Kevin: It works. Please refer to my example. Are you testing with both Ethernet cable and wireless on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine with the example below. The test environment is laptop and WiFi / WLAN (Wireless Local Area Networking).

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
import socket
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.logger import Logger


class Menu(BoxLayout):
    manager = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Menu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self._key_handler)
        # Logger.setErrorIcon = self.setErrorIcon

    def _key_handler(self, instance, key, *args):
        if key is 27:
            self.set_previous_screen()
            return True

    def is_connected(self, *args):
        motorBtn = StringProperty()
        index = NumericProperty(-1)

        try:
            socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
            self.ids.EthBtn.icon = './Asset/EE1.png'
            Logger.debug("connected")
        except OSError:
            self.ids.EthBtn.icon = './Asset/EE.png'
            Logger.error("E81:not connected")


Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class MenuApp(App):
    index = NumericProperty(-1)

    def build(self):
        my_callback = Menu()
        Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback.is_connected, 0.5)
        return my_callback    # Menu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MenuApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
<Menu>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    manager: screen_manager
    orientation: "vertical"

    ActionBar:

        size_hint_y: 0.15
        background_image: ''
        background_color: 0.349, 0.584, 0.917, 1

        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                id: actprev
                title: "[b]RheoSb[/b]"
                markup: True
                ##color: 0.105, 0.109, 0.113,1
                font_size: 100
                #app_icon: './assest/v3.jpg'
                app_icon: './Asset/VL2.png'
                with_previous: False
                ##on_release: root.set_previous_screen()
                #on_press: root.manager.current= 'home'
                on_press: root.set_previous_screen()
                on_press: root.btn_SwipeSound()

            ActionButton:
                id:errorBtn
                text:''
                icon: ''
                on_press:root.error_logPopup()

            ActionButton:
                id:EthBtn
                important: True
                text:''
                icon: './Asset/EE1.png'

            ActionButton:
                id:motorBtn
                text:''
                icon: './Asset/mm.png'

    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
```

## Output

[image: Internet Connected]
[image: Internet Disconnected]

Comment: If you don't mind could you please refer the new edit please. BackgroundScheduler()  cause me the issue!! thanks Heaps.!!

Comment: Could you please provide code for `BackgroundScheduler()`.

Comment: anyway Thank heaps always helping to solve isuues! not to trouble you anymore.. Thats allgood! ;) I'll research this further more why the code broke.. in case if you happen to find the reason.. please drop it in..

Comment: @ikolim I have tried implementing your example of checking a connection.  But even though the event is scheduled and runs it does not update the icon image.  Do you maybe have any suggestion for why that would be, please?

Comment: @Hmerman6006: With my example running, when I disconnect the WiFi, it updated the icon.